# Could anyone help me understand why moviepy is rendering at 2.5 it/s?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding, moviepy

I'm writing a program that uses moviepy to make those weird reddit thread videos with mc parkour playing in the background (real original ik), and everything is good except for when im rendering video which seems to consume a ton of memory and moves really... really slow, like 2.5 it/s. could anyone help? also im a novice programmer that has no bearing on what is conventional or proper, so sorry if my code is very bad.

```
from moviepy.video.fx.all import resize
from moviepy.video.tools.subtitles import SubtitlesClip
from moviepy.editor import (
    CompositeVideoClip,
    AudioFileClip,
    VideoFileClip,
    ImageClip,
    TextClip
)
import random
import moviepy.config as cfg
import librosa
from imagegenerator import draw_title
from audioeditor import concatenate_audios
import soundfile as sf
import numpy as np

# Constants
VIDEO_FADE_DURATION = 0.4
SPEED_FACTOR = 1.1
TEXT_WIDTH = 600
MINIMUM_FONT_SIZE = 60
FONT_COLOR = "white"
OUTLINE_COLOR = "black"
TITLE_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.25
ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.2

# Configure imagemagick binary
cfg.change_settings(
    {
        "IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY": "magick/magick.exe"
    }
)

# Ease-out function
def ease_out(t):
    return 1 - (1 - t) ** 2

# Overlap audio files
def overlap_audio_files(audio_path1, audio_path2):
    # Load the first audio file
    audio1, sr1 = librosa.load(audio_path1, sr=None)

    # Load the second audio file
    audio2, sr2 = librosa.load(audio_path2, sr=None)

    # Ensure both audio files have the same sample rate
    if sr1 != sr2:
        raise ValueError("Sample rates of the two audio files must be the same.")

    # Calculate the duration of audio2
    audio2_duration = len(audio2)

    # Tile audio1 to match the duration of audio2
    audio1 = np.tile(audio1, int(np.ceil(audio2_duration / len(audio1))))

    # Trim audio1 to match the duration of audio2
    audio1 = audio1[:audio2_duration]

    # Combine the audio files by superimposing them
    combined_audio = audio1 + audio2

    # Save the combined audio to a new file
    output_path = "temp/ttsclips/combined_audio.wav"
    sf.write(output_path, combined_audio, sr1)

    return output_path

# Generator function for subtitles with centered alignment and outline
def centered_text_generator_white(txt):
    return TextClip(
        txt,
        font=r"fonts/Invisible-ExtraBold.otf",
        fontsize=86,
        color=FONT_COLOR,
        bg_color='transparent',  # Use a transparent background
        align='center',  # Center the text
        size=(1072, 1682),
        method='caption',  # Draw a caption instead of a title
    )

# Generator function for subtitles with centered alignment and blurred outline
def centered_text_generator_black_blurred_outline(txt, blur_factor=3):
    outline_clip = TextClip(
        txt,
        font=r"fonts/Invisible-ExtraBold.otf",
        fontsize=86,
        color=OUTLINE_COLOR,
        bg_color='transparent',  # Use a transparent background
        align='center',  # Center the text
        size=(1080, 1688),
        method='caption',  # Draw a caption instead of a title
    )

    # Blur the black text (outline)
    blurred_outline_clip = outline_clip.fx(resize, 1.0 / blur_factor)
    blurred_outline_clip = blurred_outline_clip.fx(resize, blur_factor)

    return blurred_outline_clip

# Compile video function
def compile_video(title_content, upvotes, comments, tone, subreddit, video_num):
    # Set the dimensions of the video (720x1280 in this case)
    height = 1280

    # Concatenate the audios
    concatenate_audios()

    concatenated_audio_path = r"temp/ttsclips/concatenated_audio.mp3"
    title_audio_path = r"temp/ttsclips/title.mp3"

    title_audio = AudioFileClip(title_audio_path)
    concatenated_audio = AudioFileClip(concatenated_audio_path)

    # Calculate for video duration
    title_duration = title_audio.duration
    duration = concatenated_audio.duration

    # Set background
    background_path = f"saved_videos/newmcparkour.mp4"
    background = VideoFileClip(background_path)
    background_duration = background.duration
    random_start = random.uniform(0, background_duration - duration)
    background = background.subclip(random_start, random_start + duration)

    # Apply fade-out effect to both background clips
    background = background.crossfadeout(VIDEO_FADE_DURATION)

    # Generate the background image with rounded corners
    background_image_path = draw_title(title_content, upvotes, comments, subreddit)

    # Load the background image with rounded corners
    background_image = ImageClip(background_image_path)

    # Set the start of the animated title clip
    animated_background_clip = background_image.set_start(0)

    # Set the initial position of the text at the bottom of the screen
    initial_position = (90, height)

    # Calculate the final position of the text at the center of the screen
    final_position = [90, 630]

    # Animate the title clip to slide up over the course of the animation duration
    animated_background_clip = animated_background_clip.set_position(
        lambda t: (
            initial_position[0],
            initial_position[1]
            - (initial_position[1] - final_position[1])
            * ease_out(t / TITLE_ANIMATION_DURATION),
        )
    )

    # Set the duration of the animated title clip
    animated_background_clip = animated_background_clip.set_duration(
        TITLE_ANIMATION_DURATION
    )

    # Assign start times to title image
    stationary_background_clip = background_image.set_start(TITLE_ANIMATION_DURATION)

    # Assign positions to stationary title image
    stationary_background_clip = stationary_background_clip.set_position(final_position)

    # Assign durations to stationary title image
    stationary_background_clip = stationary_background_clip.set_duration(
        title_duration - TITLE_ANIMATION_DURATION
    )

    #  Select background music
    if tone == "normal":
        music_options = [
            "Anguish",
            "Garden",
            "Limerence",
            "Lost",
            "NoWayOut",
            "Summer",
            "Never",
            "Miss",
            "Touch",
            "Stellar"
        ]
    elif tone == "eerie":
        music_options = [
            "Creepy",
            "Scary",
            "Spooky",
            "Space",
            "Suspense"
        ]
    background_music_choice = random.choice(music_options)
    background_music_path = f"music/eeriemusic/{background_music_choice}.mp3"

    # Create final audio by overlapping background music and concatenated audio
    final_audio = AudioFileClip(
        overlap_audio_files(background_music_path, concatenated_audio_path)
    )

    # Release the concatenated audio
    concatenated_audio.close()

    # Create subtitles clip using the centered_text_generator
    subtitles = SubtitlesClip("temp/ttsclips/content_speechmarks.srt",
                            lambda txt: centered_text_generator_white(txt))
    subtitles_outline = SubtitlesClip("temp/ttsclips/content_speechmarks.srt",
                            lambda txt: centered_text_generator_black_blurred_outline(txt))

    # Overlay subtitles on the blurred background
    final_clip = CompositeVideoClip(
        [background, animated_background_clip, stationary_background_clip, subtitles_outline, subtitles]
    )

    # Set the final video dimensions and export the video
    final_clip = final_clip.set_duration(duration)
    final_clip = final_clip.set_audio(final_audio)

    final_clip.write_videofile(
        f"temp/videos/{video_num}.mp4",
        codec="libx264",
        fps=60,
        bitrate="8000k",
        audio_codec="aac",
        audio_bitrate="192k",
        preset="ultrafast",
        threads=8
    )

    # Release the concatenated audio
    concatenated_audio.close()

    # Release the title audio
    title_audio.close()

    # Release the background video and image
    background.close()
    background_image.close()

    # Release the final audio
    final_audio.close()

    # Release the subtitle clips
    subtitles.close()
    subtitles_outline.close()

    # Release the final video clip
    final_clip.close()
```

ive tried turning down my settings, like setting it to "ultrafast" and dropping the bitrate, but nothing seems to work. the only thing I can think of now is that there is something Im doing wrong with moviepy.

Comment: sometimes the only solution can be much faster computer.

Comment: yea, I see what you mean... but I have fairly okay specs i think. not entirely sure what all goes into rendering stuff but I have a i7-9700K cpu and 2070 super gpu. I only have 16g of ram though, do you know if that could be causing it?